# Implementation of type parameter in HashMap vs ArrayList

Tags: java, generics

`HashMap<K,V>` stores data as array of entry. i.e

```
Entry<K,V>[] table
```

and type of key and value inside Entry are K and V respectively.

But..

`ArrayList<E>` stores data as array of object. i.e.

```
Object[] elementData
```

So wondering why ArrayList doesn't use array of type E ??

Comment: `E[]` and `Entry<E>[]` are not the same thing.

Comment: HashMap does a thing, ArrayList another

Comment: Disagree that this is a duplicate; the question it is marked a duplicate of doesn't include anything about why HashMap is different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: try implementing it yourself and see what happens.  Long answer: because Java uses type erasure, and you need to know the type at run time in order to create a new array, `new E[size]` won't compile, so it can't do this without some kind of hack.  You don't need to know generic parameters to create a new array, however, as they're erased so you don't have to know them at runtime.